# Node js steam trade bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, steam

I'm trying to make a trade bot, but I have a problem with it. When I make an offer to the bot and I want to accept it, the bot doesn't do anything. Decline is working very well, but the accept is not.

https://github.com/seishun/node-steam-trade

Here is my code:

```
steam.on('tradeOffers', function(number) {
  if (number > 0) {
    offers.getOffers({
      get_received_offers: 1,
      active_only: 1,
      time_historical_cutoff: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)
    }, function(error, body) {
      if(body.response.trade_offers_received){
        body.response.trade_offers_received.forEach(function(offer) {
          if (offer.trade_offer_state == 2) {

            console.log(offer);
            if(offer.items_to_receive){
                if(!offer.items_to_give){
                    offers.acceptOffer(offer.tradeofferid);
                }else {
                    offers.declineOffer(offer.tradeofferid);
                }
            }else {
                offers.declineOffer(offer.tradeofferid);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The first if statement checking for "items_to_recieve" seems pretty pointless as you are then immediately checking for no "items_to_give". That might be where your bot is getting caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(offer.items_to_receive)` Is the problem, `offer.items_to_receive` will immediately return `false` since you are not asking for a specific item.